# Delay sign assembly programmatically

Tags: c#

I got one requirement to delay sign all the assemblies inside one folder just by double clicking the batch file. Hence, I have choosen C# Console Application to write code.

The following is the command to delay sign an assembly.

```
sn -R myAssembly.dll sgKey.snk
```

Can anybody please tell how to use the above command programmatically or is there any method exists to do the same for all the .dlls inside one folder?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow - if you have a command line you ca run to delay sign an assembly, and you have a programming language (C#, batch or whatever) that can iterate over the contents of a folder, what's left that needs figuring out?

Comment: If you're not sure on how to call a powershell script from C#, try looking at the System.Management.Automation assembly.

Comment: @Patashu - My doubt is: If I have 100 assemblies in one folder, then my managers are asking like that they should be in a position to sign all the assemblies just by double clicking on one file (batch file). They don't want to write command for each and individual .dll file.

Comment: @SomeGuy - I don't know the purpose of Powershell script for my context. Could you please elaborate on that...

Comment: @Ashokkumar Sorry, I thought you said you had a ps1, but really you have a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution assumes you are set on doing this in a C# application. This script is much more suited to a batch file.

If you don't want to get your output back, this command will do for executing on some arbitrary assembly

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"sn -R myAssembly.dll sgKey.snk");
```

Otherwise you'll need to create a ProcessStartInfo object, like so:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
   new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"sn -R myAssembly.dll sgKey.snk");
```

(I would encourage you to read up on this class and use it).

So assuming we've created some folder f with all our files in it:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in Folder.GetFiles())
{
    //Build our command string
    StringBuilder myCommand = new StringBuilder(@"sn -R ", 50);
    myCommand.Append(file.FullName);
    myCommand.Append("sgKey.snk");

    //Execute our command
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myCommand);
}
```

Alternatively, you could build a batch script that uses the same logic, and I would strongly recommend you do so. That way you keep complexity to a minimum (a single batch script doing work, rather than a tiny C# script calling a batch script to do work).